# Undo git branch --track remotes/origin/X

Tags: git, remote-branch

Using git branch --set-upstream resulted in this message:

```
The --set-upstream flag is deprecated and will be removed. Consider
using --track or --set-upstream-to
```

Without thinking about it too much and assuming verb-object order, I then tried

```
git branch --track remotes/origin/X
```

This resulted in

```
Branch remotes/origin/X set up to track local branch X
```

Argh, not what I wanted. The remote was supposed to be tracked, not do the tracking. How can I undo this and set the remote branch not to track anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically you don't have to do anything at all: you've created a new local branch named `remotes/origin/X`, which is terribly confusing but not actually forbidden (it probably should be rejected), and that local branch tracks local branch `X`.

(If you have color turned on, you can see this in `git branch -a` output: `remotes/origin/X` will be in black while actual remote branches will be in red.)

The simplest thing to do at this point, though, is just to delete that confusingly-named local branch:

```
$ git branch -d remotes/origin/X
```

Even if you have both a local branch named `remotes/origin/X` *and* a (really, actually) remote `remotes/origin/X` (so that both show up in the `git branch -a` output), the above just deletes the local one.  Again, the in-various-colors output from `git branch -a` can be reassuring here (though I can't reproduce it in SO text).